# Cast features to ClassLabel

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I have a dataset with type dictionary which I converted to `Dataset`:

ds = datasets.Dataset.from_dict(bio_dict)

The shape now is:

```
Dataset({
    features: ['id', 'text', 'ner_tags', 'input_ids', 'attention_mask', 'label'],
    num_rows: 8805
})
```

When I use the `train_test_split` function of `Datasets` I receive the following error:

```
train_testvalid = ds.train_test_split(test_size=0.5, shuffle=True, stratify_by_column="label")
```

> ValueError: Stratifying by column is only supported for ClassLabel
> column, and column label is Sequence.

How can I change the type to ClassLabel so that stratify works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should apply the following [class_encode_column](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.class_encode_column) function:

```
ds = ds.class_encode_column("label")
```